# Need to update account checkbox to true,if account has more contact

Tags: trigger

```
public class checkCheckboxonAcc {
    public static void newContact(List<Account> acclist) {
        List<contact> conlist = new List<Contact> ();
        for(Account acc : acclist) {
            conlist.AccountId = acclist.Name;
            conlist.Only_Default_Contact__c = true;
        }
        insert conlist;
    }
    public static void updatecheckbox(List<contact> con) {
        Set<Id> AccId = new Set<Id> ();
        for(contact c : con) {
            AccId.add(c.AccountId);
        }
        List<Account> AccUpdates = new List<Account>();
        for(AggregateResult ar : [select count(id) , AccountId from Contact where AccountId IN :AccId group by AccountId having count(id)  >1 ]){
            updatedAccounts.add(new Account(Id = (Id)ar.get('AccountId'), Only_Default_Contact__c=false));    
        } 
        if(AccUpdates !=null)
        {
            update AccUpdates;
        }
    }
}
```

I doesn't able to clear the error after saving this class. Someone help me to found a perfect solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit your post to include the complete verbatim error and line, and use the formatting tools to format your code properly.

Comment: Sure @DavidReed  but am new to this. So can't know how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void newContact(List<Account> acclist) {
    List<contact> conlist = new List<Contact> ();
    for(Account acc : acclist) {
        conlist.AccountId = acclist.Name;
        conlist.Only_Default_Contact__c = true;
    }
    insert conlist;
}
```

You're trying to assign a value to a list, not a record, which is not allowed. Also, you'd be trying to assign a non-Id to an Id field, also not allowed.

Here's the fixed version:

```
public static void newContact(Account[] acclist) {
    Contact[] newContactRecords = new Contact[0];
    for(Account accountRecord: acclist) {
        newContactRecords.add(
            new Contact(
                AccountId = accountRecord.Id,
                LastName = accountRecord.Name,
                Only_Default_Contact__c = true
            )
        );
    }
    insert newContactRecords;
}
```

Note the use of `new Contact` to create the record in memory.

---

P.S. AccUpdates will never be null, no need to check:

```
// Remove this check //
if(AccUpdates !=null)
```

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox My errors are cleared and one clarification with you. That I nedd to create two or one triggers

Comment: @Mickey01 You would need two triggers, one for Accounts, and one for Contacts.

Comment: Thanks am working on this.